# Can I see transactions in bitcoin-qt without downloading blocks? if I have a server with blocks on the local network?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-qt-setup

I have server with `bitcoind` (synchronized), port 18443 opened. And I tried to connect to rpc server with `bitcoin-qt` in my mac. With this configuration:

```
regtest=1
rpcuser=<login>
rpcpassword=<pass>
rpc_connect=<ip to server>
```

But `bitcoin-qt` writes that it is synchronizing, and to use the application you have to wait.

Can I use `bitcoin-qt` without synchronization?

*P.S. Sorry for my english*

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t work because the software doesn’t support operating like that. You can not connect bitcoin-qt to a remote RPC server.